# Changing Folder permissions with C# doesn't seem to be working

Tags: c#, permissions, acl

I'm really out of my comfort zone when it comes to permisions. But I want to create a folder and give all users Full Control over it.

```
DirectoryInfo NewDir = Directory.CreateDirectory(@"C:\Test");
DirectorySecurity dSecur = NewDir.GetAccessControl();
FileSystemAccessRule fAccess =
    new FileSystemAccessRule("Users", FileSystemRights.FullControl,AccessControlType.Allow);
dSecur.AddAccessRule(fAccess);
NewDir.SetAccessControl(dSecur);
```

But the pic below shows that Users Still doesn't have Full Control.

[image]

Am I missing something? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want full control then you need to pass both `ContainerInherit` and `ObjectInherit` for the `InheritanceFlags`.

```
new FileSystemAccessRule(
    User, 
    FileSystemRights.FullControl, 
    InheritanceFlags.ContainerInherit | InheritanceFlags.ObjectInherit,
    PropagationFlags.InheritOnly, 
    AccessControlType.Allow
)
```

And be sure that run under a user with enough rights to grant full control the other user.